# Nginx location запретить доступ к нескольким папкам и их содержимому

Tags: nginx

Как запретить доступ к одной папке я разобрался:

```
location ^~ /views/ {    deny all;}
```

Но как запретить доступ сразу к нескольким папкам так и не могу понять! уже много разных комбинаций перепробовал. Не думаю что выходом является для каждой папки создание своего локейшена. Может кто знает как решить проблемку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~* ^/(loc1|loc2)($|\/) {deny all;}
```

Comment: Верно + необходимо расположить выше локейшена который отправляет php файлы на бекэнд.